# is pre_get_comments not working?

Tags: plugin-development, comments

I am following through the "Professional Wordpress Plugin Development" book from WROX and I wanted to use this piece of code I found in it (I switched pre_get_posts with pre_get_comments) for my plugin, but for some reason it isn't working? And when I googled it, I found multiple people who said that "pre_get_comments" stopped working sometime this year.
Is this true? Because I can't find anything about it on the wordpress codex. And what hook should I be using instead then?

```
do_action_ref_array( 'pre_get_comments', 'random_order_comments');
function random_order_comments( $query )
{
    if( is_single() ){
            $query->set( ‘orderby’, ‘rand’ );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any reason why `pre_get_comments` would not be working, [it's still in core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/comment.php#L485), however...

you've got a few problems in your code -

`do_action_ref_array` is what core calls to trigger the action, you add your own functions to the action queue via [`add_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action).

`orderby` is the field name you want to order by, `order` controls how it's ordered, and `ASC` and `DESC` are the only valid values for `order`.

[`WP_Comment_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) returns an array of comments, you could use [PHP's shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to randomize the order.

Also note that you have curly typographer quotes in your code above around `orderby` and `rand`, which will throw a PHP fatal error. You do have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), yes?

Comment: I have it enabled now! And thank you for the respond.